# How can I print meta tags of external webpage?

Tags: php, dom

The code should show all the html lines with the tag "meta" why it don't show it?

```
    $html = 'http://www.google.es/';

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents("$html"));
    $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName("meta");
    if($items->length > 0){
        echo $items->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }
```

Comment: Ehm, `<meta>` tags don't have node values.

Comment: so, for show the <meta> tags what can I do?

Comment: That depends on what you want to show? A single attribute, more than one attribute, the tag, the entire tag with attributes, etc etc. Take a look at [DOMElement](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php), which is what `$items->item(0)` returns. All the info you need, should be in there.

Comment: I want show a single attribute, "charset= UTF-8" for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this. Note that Xpath queries might be faster though, since you won't need to loop through every `meta` tag manually.

```
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName("meta");
if($items->length > 0){
    echo $items->item(0)->getAttribute('charset'); // echoes "UTF-8"
}
```

See in action here: https://3v4l.org/ZFHuu

Comment: I'm trying to show it from google     $html = 'http://www.google.es/'; so it don't print nothing..

Comment: `$html = file_get_contents('https://www.google.es');`..? It's just an example for reference. Also note that that page doesn't include a `<meta charset="UTF-8">` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for the Xpath expression mentioned by Loek:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$charset = $xpath->evaluate('string(//meta/@charset)');
var_dump($charset);
```

Output:

```
string(5) "UTF-8"
```

If here is no `meta` element with a `charset` attribute the returned value will be an empty string.

Comment: Awesome! I always mess up my Xpath's so this is nice.